# Calling non-static methods from static methods with use of "self"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python, so please be... kind?

Anyway, I need use a static method to call another method, which requires the use of "self" (and thus, a normal method I believe). I am working with [Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon), a Python implementation of Telegram. I have tried other questions on SO, but I just can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

An overview of the program (please correct me if I'm wrong):

1) interactive_telegram_client is a child class of telegram_client, and it creates an instance.

```
#interactive_telegram_client.py
class InteractiveTelegramClient(TelegramClient):
    super().__init__(session_user_id, api_id, api_hash, proxy)
```

2) When the InteractiveTelegramClient runs, it adds an update_handler `self.add_update_handler(self.update_handler)` to constantly check for messages received/sent, and prints it to screen

```
#telegram_client.py
def add_update_handler(self, handler):
    """Adds an update handler (a function which takes a TLObject,
      an update, as its parameter) and listens for updates"""
    if not self.sender:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "You should connect at least once to add update handlers.")

    self.sender.add_update_handler(handler)

#interactive_telegram_client.py
@staticmethod
def update_handler(update_object):
    try:
        if type(update_object) is UpdateShortMessage:
            if update_object.out:
                print('You sent {} to user #{}'.format(update_object.message,
                                                       update_object.user_id))
            else:
                print('[User #{} sent {}]'.format(update_object.user_id,
                                                  update_object.message))
```

Now, my aim here is to send back an auto-reply message upon receiving a message. Thus, I *think* that adding a call to method `InteractiveTelegramClient.send_ack(update_object)` in the `update_handler` method would serve my needs.

```
#interactive_telegram_client.py
def send_ack(self, update_object):
    entity = update_object.user_id
    message = update_object.message
    msg, entities = parse_message_entities(message)
    msg_id = utils.generate_random_long()

    self.invoke(SendMessageRequest(peer=get_input_peer(entity),
        message=msg,random_id=msg_id,entities=entities,no_webpage=False))
```

However, as you can see, I require the `self` to invoke this function (based on the [readme](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon#id12), where I assume `client` to refer to the same thing as `self`). Since the method `update_handler` is a static one, `self` is not passed through, and as such I cannot invoke the call as such.

My possible strategies which have failed include:

1) Instantiating a new client for the auto-reply
- Creating a new client/conversation for each reply...

2) Making all the methods non-static
- Involves a tremendous amount of work since other methods modified as well

3) Observer pattern (sounds like a good idea, I tried, but due to a lack of skills, not succeeded)

I was wondering if there's any other way to tackle this problem? Or perhaps it's actually easy, just that I have some misconception somewhere?

Forgot to mention that due to some restrictions on my project, I can only use Telethon, as opposed to looking at other alternatives. Adopting another library (like an existing auto-reply one) is allowed, though I did not really look into that since merging that and Telethon may be too difficult for me...

Comment: If your `update_handler(..)` needs an instance (logically speaking) to work with, then it should probably not be a static method..

Comment: I thought so too, but due to the fact that several other methods (from other classes etc) call upon this, it is quite difficult to change it to non-static, but I will take another look at this if it's a possible solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> based on the readme, where I assume client to refer to the same thing as self

Correct, since the `InteractiveTelegramClient` subclasses the `TelegramClient` and hence, `self` is an instance of the extended client.

> Instantiating a new client for the auto-reply - Creating a new client/conversation for each reply

This would require you to create another authorization *and* send another code request to login, because you can't work with the same `*.session` at the same time.

> Making all the methods non-static - Involves a tremendous amount of work since other methods modified as well

It doesn't require such amount of work. Consider the following example:

```python
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def do_something(self):
        Example.other_method()

    @staticmethod
    def other_method():
        print('hello, world!')
```

Is equivalent to:

```python
class Example:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def do_something(self):
        self.other_method()

    @staticmethod
    def other_method():
        print('hello, world!')
```

It doesn't matter whether you use `self.` or the class name to refer to a static method from within the class. Since the `InteractiveClientExample` already uses `self.`, all you would have to do would be changing:

```python
@staticmethod
def update_handler(update_object):
```

for

```python
def update_handler(self, update_object):
```

For more on the `@staticmethod` decorator, you can [refer to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=staticmethod#staticmethod).

Comment: Is this question still relative? I'd like to see the complete script in action.

Comment: @Mand what do you mean exactly? Perhaps you have a different question?